# Java: When does strings go into string const pool?

Tags: java, string

Here is my code:

```
String s = new String("1"); // here I know that "1" is created in const pool    
String s2 = new String("1") + new String("1");
```

Does "11" created in the String pool immediately in this code? If not, should I invoke `s2.intern()` to put "11" to String pool?

--------------udapte 22/9/2016---------------------

Here I have somethings confuse me:
Both *new Stirng("1")* and *new String("1") + new String("1")* invoke the same native method *System.arraycopy* which I learn from JDK6.

**Now why does "1" will be created in String pool but "11" does't?**
Does anything make differences in StringBuilder? Maybe method "append" or ...?

I will be appreciated for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> But does "11" created in const pool immediately in this code?

No. It will not be created in the String constants pool. `StringBuilder` will be used to join the two `"1"`s together to form `"11"` which will be on the heap.

> Should I invoke s2.intern() to put `11` to const pool?

Yes. You should explicitly invoke `intern` if you want to to put `11` (got by adding 2 `"1"`s (and not the literal `"11"`) in the String constants pool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.StringBuilder will invoke toString() finally, and  excutes "new String(value, 0, count)" .So After excuting "new String(value, 0, count)" , "11" still in the heap?

Comment: *Why* should he invoke `intern()` to put `11` into the constant pool?

Comment: @GanGan He's answered that.

Comment: @EJP - Well, I think the OP meant to ask if calling `intern()` would add the String `11` that he got (`s2`) .

Answer (score 0):

String s will not be created in the common pool. The new operator will cause the JVM to allocate memory for the new string literal "1" in heap memory.

```
String s1 = "1"; // Common pool
String s2 = new String("1"); // heap allocated memory
```

In your example:

```
String s2 = new String("1") + new String("1");
```

As for your question : https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html

The result of concatenating two strings will be allocated on heap memory.

Comment: There is no String s in your answer

Comment: wow, thanks for your share! What I confused is that  "new String("1")" but not "String s = "1" ".Whatever, I'm so grateful to you for yout answer.

Comment: @Sentry But there is a `String s` in the question.

Comment: @EJP I should read better before I comment. Or sleep more.